# Magento 2 - Check login for page in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, login

I'm developing a custom module. How to check if a user is logged in or not? If not logged in, redirect the user to login page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should take a look at the Account Create controller: **vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Create.php**, we can see how to check the session customer.

So, we can follow this way, example controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Account;

class Check extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $session;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->session = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        if (!$this->session->isLoggedIn()) {
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setPath('customer/account/login');
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
    }
}
```